# Extracting data from stream tags

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm trying to pull data from stream tags that add an **MPSK SNR Estimator** block. The tag contains a key and a value.  In the code there is an attempt to filter the tag by the key: 'snr'.
I added my own block to the [flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVtOE.png), but it doesn't work correctly.
**I want my SNR data(SNR values) to be written to a file**(type->float32), but this is not happening. Instead, it is displayed in the console in a complex form.
[My console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSw2a.png), where data is displayed for some reason.

```
import numpy as np
from gnuradio import gr
import pmt

class blk(gr.sync_block):  # other base classes are basic_block, decim_block, interp_block
    """Embedded Python Block example - a simple multiply const"""
    def __init__(self):  # only default arguments here
        """arguments to this function show up as parameters in GRC"""
        gr.sync_block.__init__(
            self,
            name='Tag_Snr',   
            in_sig=[np.complex64],
            out_sig=[np.float32]
            # out_sig=None
        )
        # if an attribute with the same name as a parameter is found,
        # a callback is registered (properties work, too).

    def work(self, input_items, output_items):
        tags = self.get_tags_in_window(0, 0, len(input(input_items[0])))
        for tag in tags:
            if tag.key == 'snr':
                value = pmt.to_python(tag.value)
                # print("value:", value, type(value))
                output_items[0] = value
                return len(output_items[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            output_items[0] = value
            return len(output_items[0])
```

That's a bug, or rather four bugs in two lines:

1. Basic Python logical bug: `return` immediately ends your current function. That's not what you want here.
2. Logic bug / GNU Radio misunderstanding: What you return from a work function tells the GNU Radio runtime how many items you've produced. You claim you have produced a full output buffer, but you really only got one value. So, that's wrong.
3. Logic bug: you overwrite `output_items[0]`, which is the whole first output stream, with a single value. That's definitely not what you want. You need something like `output_items[0][output_counter] = value`
4. Logic bug/GNU Radio: You declared your block to be `sync_block`, which means you inherently consume as many items as you produce (i.e., return from the work function).
   That does not reflect the logical function you want your block to perform, which is *not* converting each input sample into an output sample. You need the general `gr.block`, not `gr.sync_block`, and you need to call `consume_each` explicitly, and return the actual number of items you've produced when you're done processing the tags, and not right after the first tag.

If you haven't, the  [official GNU Radio tutorials](https://tutorials.gnuradio.org) walk you through things like [what it means for a block to `return` something](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=Creating_Your_First_Block#Components_of_a_Python_Block), [how to write values to the output](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=Creating_Your_First_Block#Editing_Work_Function) and so on.